# Java heap dump & shut down - what order?

Tags: java, jvm

I would like to detect an `OutOfMemoryError`, take a heap dump, and automatically exit the Java program. Say I have the following command-line arguments for my JVM:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/usr/tmp
```

Which happens first? Does the process dump memory and then quit, or the other way around?

Comment: Don't do the kill.  Have a top level try-catch and do a syste.exit.

Comment: Did you found out the answer about what is the order? Actually I am also facing the issue, that sometime dump file is generation is some time it is not on OOM. And I am guessing there must be something to do with "order of exit" and "dump file creation" on OOM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would rather rely on calling into a script that handles the ordering more deterministically i.e.

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/<SomeStandardLocation>/heapAndQuit.sh"
```

heapAndQuit.sh will then employ a method to find the `pid` of the current process. 
One simple way to identify the pid is to use the log file location your process is writing to

```
lsof | grep /var/tmp/<yourlogfileName> | cut -d " " -f1 | uniq
```

I will then use `jmap` to dump and `kill -9` subsequently

Comment: This is what I started doing instead, so far it seems to be the far more extensible option. Thanks!

Comment: For tomcat, the more elegant way to find pid is `TOMCATPID=$(cat tomcat.pid)`

Comment: @Ram does this work in spark-submit too ? i.e. spark job application

Comment: As it turned out, jmap collected heapdump withput stack frames content for me.

Stack wasn't visible in VisualVM, but `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` collected heapdump with stack frames present.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using OpenJDK you can be sure when you are going to run the command set by -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError option.

Code taken from the OpenJDK source code. See: [debug.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/1943edc6f06a/src/share/vm/utilities/debug.cpp)

```
void report_java_out_of_memory(const char* message) {
  static jint out_of_memory_reported = 0;

  // A number of threads may attempt to report OutOfMemoryError at around the
  // same time. To avoid dumping the heap or executing the data collection
  // commands multiple times we just do it once when the first threads reports
  // the error.
  if (Atomic::cmpxchg(1, &out_of_memory_reported, 0) == 0) {
    // create heap dump before OnOutOfMemoryError commands are executed
    if (HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError) {    
      tty->print_cr("java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: %s", message);
      HeapDumper::dump_heap_from_oome();
    }

    if (OnOutOfMemoryError && OnOutOfMemoryError[0]) {
      VMError err(message);
      err.report_java_out_of_memory();
    }
  }
}
```

Just in case a short explanation:

1. First of all check if the HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError option was set. In that case run dump_heap_from_oome()
2. Sencondly if the OnOutOfMemoryError option was set, run report_java_out_of_memory()

So, for sure if you are using OpenJDK your process will dump memory and then quit.

Answer (score 7):

In Java version 8u92 the VM arguments

- `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError`
- `-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError`

were added, see the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u92-relnotes-2949471.html).

> **ExitOnOutOfMemoryError**
>   When you enable this option, the JVM exits on the
>   first occurrence of an out-of-memory error. It can be used if you
>   prefer restarting an instance of the JVM rather than handling out of
>   memory errors.
>
> **CrashOnOutOfMemoryError**
>   If this option is enabled, when an
>   out-of-memory error occurs, the JVM crashes and produces text and
>   binary crash files.

Enhancement Request: [JDK-8138745](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138745) (parameter naming is wrong though  [JDK-8154713](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154713), `ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` instead of `ExitOnOutOfMemory`)

Answer (score 6):

You shall use

> ExitOnOutOfMemoryError or
>   CrashOnOutOfMemoryError

and

> HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

OpenJDK JVM (Hotspot) at first takes the heap dump and then crashes out or exits as opted for.

To get a clearer understanding you may refer to JVM source file taking care of this particular logic.

https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/8641949eb21f/src/share/vm/utilities/debug.cpp

Answer (score 1):

I think this would heavily depend on the actual JVM implementation you are using. I'd like to believe that the JVM in use employs some intelligent ordering, first performing a heap dump than killing the machine. However, in my opinion you should not rely on the order of options.