# taking spark job thread dump

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, garbage-collection

I am using spark-sql-2.4.5v with java8 in my application.
My application is failing due to OOM: Heap space issue

I am would like to take thread dump to analyze the GC logs.
But I am not sure where and how to take the thread-dump on spark-job which is running on "yarn cluster" mode.

I added below configuration and trigger my spark-submit

```
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-verbose:gc -Xloggc:hdfs::/user/xxxx/gc_log/$app_id/gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" \

--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-verbose:gc -Xloggc:hdfs::/user/xxxx/gc_log/$app_id/gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" \
```

But  "gc.log" file not got generated.

What am I doing wrong here ?
how to get "gc.log" file ?

Comment: I don't think `Xloggc` supports `hdfs` as it is a JVM flag, not a Spark flag (vanilla JVM doesn't know anything about hdfs). You probably need to store the log on local disk and move it somewhere from there.

Comment: Perhaps you can try `-xx:+HeapDumpPath=<local-path>` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html. And yes, the path should be local not hdfs.

Comment: @ollik1, the thing is i am running in "yarn cluster" mode with 60 executors ...I see java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid6673.hprof ... in log ...but not sure where it has saved/dumped ? how to figure out the node / where it saved/dump ??

Comment: @mazaneicha I trie with throwing error as  Unrecognized VM option 'HeapDumpPath:/tmp/.log'

Comment: @mazaneicha Unrecognized option: -xx:+HeapDumpPath=/tmp/.log

Comment: Oops, `--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/heapdumps"` works for me. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @mazaneicha thanks for quick response...are you running "yarn client" or "yarn cluster" mode ? if in cluster mode how do you know on which node /tmp/heapdumps this will be located/saved ?

Comment: it is going to be on the node where OOM'ed container was running.

Comment: @Shasu you can execute a custom script on OOM like here in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19434611/11140326

Perhaps upload the dump somewhere that is easier to access

Comment: @mazaneicha anywhere i get trace of what is that container id ?